# Hi! How do I store the fields and display the results on a different activity ? Please

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-button

I want the fields entered by the user to be displayed as a list view of the studentnoText and courseField in a new activity..

```
public class Student extends Activity {

    private String totalStudents [];

    private EditText studentnoText;
    private EditText studentnameText;
    private EditText courseField;
    private Spinner departmentSpinner;
    private EditText dobField;
    private Button registerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);

    studentnoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentnoText);
    studentnameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentnameText);
    dobField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobField);
    courseField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseField);
    departmentSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.departmentSpinner);
    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

}

    public void registerButtonPressed (View view){




        Log.v("Register","Register Pressed!");
    }

}
```

Comment: **-1**: Cool to know what you want…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE PUT EXTRA TO SEND DATA**

```
mIntent.putExtra("TEXT", studentnoText.gettext().toString());
mIntent.putExtra("TEXT_1", studentName.gettext().toString());
```

**USE GET EXTRA TO GET DATA**

```
String strNO,strName;
strNO= extras.getString("TEXT");
strName = extras.getString("TEXT_1");
```

Comment: It is giving me an error on mIntent. It suggests that i create a local variable ??

Comment: Intent mIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);mIntent.putExtra("TEXT", studentnoText.gettext().toString());
mIntent.putExtra("TEXT_1", studentName.gettext().toString()); startActivity(mIntent);

Comment: Are these all coded in to the registerButtonPressed method ?

Comment: A.this is giving me an error (what is it ?) what should i have there ?

Comment: brother A is your Student  Activity and B is your NEXT activity in which you have list view.

Comment: Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

Comment: bro intent is Intent intent; you create in list activity and past get extra code in list activity;

Comment: Intent mIntent = new Intent(Student.this, Register.class);
  mIntent.putExtra("studentno", studentnoText.getText().toString());
  
  String strNo;
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  strNo = extras.getString("studentno");

Comment: Intent mIntent = new Intent(Student.this, Register.class); mIntent.putExtra("studentno", studentnoText.getText().toString());

Comment: startActivity(mIntent);

Comment: and in register class use String strNo; Intent intent = getIntent(); Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); strNo = extras.getString("studentno");

Comment: and when you get the strNo in string and use it on list view which you want to populate it

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
     
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.registerList);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers); 
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     
     String strNo; 
     Intent intent = getIntent(); 
     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
     strNo = extras.getString("studentno");
     
     
     
   }

Comment: WHAT ERROR CAN YOU EXPLAIN??

Comment: when i run the app, the first screen is where i enter the student details when i click the button register a pop dialog appears with UNFORTUNATELY, STUDENT HAS STOPPED.. then it transfers to the register screen.. with nothing displayed. i want the student no to be displayed ONLY.

Comment: please email me your email and i will sent u the entire app.. ?

Comment: [2014-04-19 21:48:15 - Student] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=app.student/app.activities.Student }
[2014-04-19 21:48:15 - Student] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: Above is the log cat code that is displayed as red colour when the register button is pressed..

Comment: Can you please check the logcat ??

Comment: plz online on hangout my id is singh.satnam02@gmail.com

Comment: yes you can show student detail while click on number